# How can I build this query in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Hope someone will help me to build this query. I need to get values from database which are belong to one particular user. These are the columns which I need to get.

```
01. city_name // From city table
02. district_name // From district table
03. category_name // From category table
04. subscription_period // From tutors table
05. date_registered // From tutors table
```

I have already got values tutor_id, city_id and category_id respectively `1, 53, 5`

My address table has `city_id` column, `City` table has `district_id` column, category table has `category_id` column and tutor table has `tutor_id` and `address_id`.

I tried something like this, but this is not working.

```sql
SELECT city_name, district_name, category_name, subscription_period AS sp, date_registered AS date
FROM tutors AS t
INNER JOIN district AS d 
INNER JOIN city ON city.district_id = d.district_id
INNER JOIN address ON address.city_id = 50
INNER JOIN category
WHERE t.tutor_id = 1 AND category.category_id= 5
```

My expecting result should have 1 row as output but this query give me more rows as output

**My SQL Tables**

```
CREATE TABLE tutors (
tutor_id SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
address_id SMALLINT NOT NULL,
tutor_name VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
subscription_period SMALLINT NOT NULL,
date_registered TIMESTAMP  NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY (tutor_id)
); 

CREATE TABLE address (
address_id SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
address VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL, 
city_id SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (address_id)
);

CREATE TABLE district(
district_id SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
district_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY (district_id)
);

CREATE TABLE city(
city_id SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
city_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
district_id SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (city_id)
);

CREATE TABLE category (
category_id SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
category_name VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY (category_id)
);

CREATE TABLE tutor_category(
tutor_id SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
category_id SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (tutor_id)
);
```

Comment: You join 5 tables with only 2 `ON` conditions. Usually, one needs 4 conditions to join 5 tables.

Comment: My expecting result should have 1 row as output but this query give me more rows as output

Comment: the best thing you will do is to create dummy tables with data on it so we can play and get your desired result.

Comment: check my question I updated it with my tables...

Comment: no it gives more rows as oupput

Comment: Subscription_period is missing in tables above could you add that to the create tables above? And provide us with sample data?

Comment: This a SQL FIDDLE demo I was preparing. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b8e33/1

Comment: By the way, your table design seems quite good. Except the table `tutor_category` which probably needs the `(tutor_id, category_id)` as `PRIMARY KEY`.

Comment: @ypercube: *‘Usually, one needs 4 conditions to join 5 tables’* – unless, of course, one uses MySQL, where INNER JOIN is synonymous with CROSS JOIN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT c.city_name, 
       d.district_name, 
       c.category_name, 
       t.subscription_period AS sp, 
       t.date_registered AS date
FROM tutors t
   INNER JOIN address a ON t.address_id = a.address_id 
   INNER JOIN city c ON c.city_id  = a.city_id 
   INNER JOIN district d ON c.district_id = d.district_id 
   INNER JOIN tutor_category tc on t.tutor_id = tc.tutor_id 
   INNER JOIN category cat on tc.category_id = cat.category_id 
WHERE t.tutor_id = 1 AND cat.category_id= 5 AND c.city_id = 50
```

You need to `JOIN` on your tables to ensure you only receive the desired results.

If you are receiving duplicate rows that are identical, you are probably doing something wrong or the definitions you provided are not correct (it appears that this is the case indeed). You could "solve" the issue by adding `GROUP BY` or `DISTINCT` to your query but that is not the best approach.

Comment: Its giving 28 rows as result. why is it?

Comment: Depends on what data is your tables -- are they duplicated rows?

Comment: post the results and we can explain.

Comment: I didn't see that you were querying for city_id = 50 -- you can add that to your where clause to filter that as well.  I'll edit my answer to include, but again, still depends on your data.

Comment: @TharangaNuwan No way. This query cannot give more than 1 row. Not with the Primary Keys you have. And I don't see `subscription_period` in any of these 6 tables, so there must be something you are not telling us, and you are running a different query probably.

Comment: Then your table structure above is not how it is in your DB.  Your structure above implies all 1-1 relationships.  Good luck -- add DISTINCT and you should be ok.  See edits...

Comment: @ypercube sorry I forgot it to add to the tutor table I just add it

Comment: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f6d7e/1 Now add some data, so you can see if the query above works.

Comment: @sgeddes DISTINCT work for me. But can you explain something about my tables structure. Is it wrong structure?

Comment: @TharangaNuwan: Shows us 2 (no need for the whole 28) rows that you get and the actual query you are running. You are probably running something else if you get duplicates. `DISTINCT` should not be needed here.

Comment: I don't know how you could possibly get multiple records running the above query (without DISTINCT).  Your relationship with Primary Keys says you can only have 1 tutor_id, and that tutor can only have 1 address_id, and that address can only have 1 city_id, and that city can only have 1 district_id, and 1 tutor can only have 1 category :-)  I imagine you have a different primary key in your tutor_category table.

Comment: @sgeddes yes. I have the same category_id number 28 times in my tutor_category table. is it the problem?

Comment: @TharangaNuwan Look at your tutor_category table. Especially to your primary key. What is you primary key?

Comment: Exact and why wasn't it defined in your table?

Comment: You probably need to define the `(tutor_id, category_id)` as the `Primary Key` there (or at least as a `UNIQUE` key).

Comment: Ok.. I got it.. Thanks for all

Comment: @Tharanga Nuwan, next time please provide sample data and a working structure. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4ab455/1

Comment: @ypercube -- no problem at all -- walked away for a few minutes -- many thanks.